# mysql action on data insert

Tags: mysql, time, triggers

I have table with 3 Column's:
"Enter-time" "Exit-time" "Calc-time". All 3 are "TIME" sql type.

Is there any way to create task for each row insert to "Enter-time" and "Exit-time",
it will auto run TIMEDIFF and add the result to "Calc-time" ?

Thanks!

---

Is it a good idea to use 2 triggers to calculate time diffrence using mysql, or using PHP is better?

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `test` $$
    CREATE TRIGGER `test` BEFORE INSERT ON `5_2012`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      set NEW.chour = NEW.exit - NEW.enter;
```

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `test2` $$
    CREATE TRIGGER `test2` BEFORE UPDATE ON `5_2012`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      set NEW.chour = NEW.exit - NEW.enter;
```